# How do I get the odoo9.0 inventory management source code/

Tags: odoo-9

How do I get the odoo inventory management source code.

```
Please let me know
```

Answer (score 0):

Please download Inventory Management from the following URL for Odoo 9

[Inventory Management Module](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/stock/)